# Does candidate feature means the point in feature space?

Tags: terminology

The CMU professor is using the term "attribute" [here](https://youtu.be/p4wlQnZcBrg?t=3940)

> They are 1 2 3 4 5 6 attributes

to describe TABLE 2.1 in [Tom M. Mitchell. Machine Learning (free)](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf)

[image]

usually, those 6 columns are also called features, so, there are 6 **features** in that table.

That professor uses the term "candidate feature" here

[Every potential binary function is a candidate feature](https://youtu.be/XPGaTGTD7o0?t=841)

obviously, "candidate feature" is different to "feature".

Does candidate feature means the point in feature space?

**Note:** There are 6 features while [the number of candidate features in this example is $2^{96}$](https://youtu.be/XPGaTGTD7o0?t=444)

Answer (score 4):

**Candidate features** are all given characteristics of an instance *[Sky, AirTemp, Humidity, Wind, Water, Forecast]* which come into consideration to predict its class label *[EnjoySport]*.

Model accuracy and training speed can be significantly compromised by irrelevant or redundant features which can lead to overfitting. Hence, it might be a good idea to remove superfluous features before fitting (**feature selection**).

The ones you end up using to train your classifier are called **features**.